# Turn this data value into variables?

Tags: jquery

does anyone know how I can change this script around to be written into variables?
For example, OP1 = true/false, OP2, OP3 etc....

Here's a working fiddle that was created by a helpful member of the stack community :)
http://jsfiddle.net/SSPax/17/

The HTML look like this:

```
<ul id="myUL">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="special[]" value="op1" />1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="special[]" value="op2" />2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="special[]" value="op3" />3</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Push Me First" id="nextquestion1" />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Push Me Second" id="getStoredValues" />
```

And the script is:

```
$('#nextquestion1').click(function() {
    $('#myUL :checkbox').each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $.data(document.body, $this.attr('value'), $this.is(':checked'));
    });
});

$('#getStoredValues').click(function () {   
    $.each($.data(document.body), function(key, value) {
        alert('Name= '+ key + ' Value= ' + value);
    });
});
```

Comment: I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) to learn some basics.

Comment: Thank you :)! That is much better than the javascript tutorials online :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the name-value pairs into an object.  An object serves as a collection of name/value pairs.  You can easily set or query it.

```
var myData = {};
myData['foo'] = 42;
alert(myData['foo'])
```